# Meteor return response from server method to client

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, mollie

I am trying to integrate a payment API. The method I'm using to create a payment should return an object. And in fact it does, but it's just that I can't get the object back to the client.

I know that this happens because the method to API is executed asynchronously, while method on server is executed synchronously (If I'm not mistaken). But still I can't figure out how to do it, and I am hoping you guys can help me out.

Client side call to server:

```
Meteor.call('createPaymentLink',NewBooking, TotalAmount ,function(result) {
            console.log(result);
});
```

Server side call to API:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'createPaymentLink': function(bookingID, amount) {

      //Create Booking No.
      // First two digits = First two digits of booking ID
      // Last two digits = Last two digits of Customer ID
      var CustomerId = Bookings.findOne({_id: bookingID}).CustomerID;
      var FirstPart = CustomerId.substring(0,2);
      var LastPart = bookingID.slice(-2);
      var rightNow = new Date();
      var OrderDate = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");

      var CustomerBookingCode = (FirstPart + OrderDate + LastPart).toUpperCase();

      mollieClient.payments.create({
          amount:      amount,
          description: "Booking code: "+bookingID,
          redirectUrl: "https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/"
      }, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(payment) {
          return payment;
          //Bookings.update({_id: bookingID}, {$set: {payment_id : PaymentUrl}});
      }));     
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the callback is the error, which will be `null` if everything worked!  Try this:

```
Meteor.call('createPaymentLink',NewBooking, TotalAmount ,function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No luck though:( Both err and result return undefined in the browser console.